# Android Adapter and convertView Recycling Behavior

Tags: android, performance, android-adapter

I have a question that after searching SO and Google I can't find an answer to. When working with an adapter in Android its good practice to reuse the list item view by using the `convertView` parameter in the `getView()` method. My question is this, if I make a change to `convertView`, will that change persist to future calls to `getView()`?

For example:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            // if i call this method here, will all future views passed into convertView
            // also have this set??
            // From what I know about Java and objects I would guess yes
            // but I'm not 100% sure how Android processes the convertView behind the scenes
            ((ViewGroup) convertView).setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        // currently setDescendantFocusability is called here,
        // I want to move it to where it above to help improve performance
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: I heard somewhere that you should use convertView as readonly. May be here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think so.

1. The converted views you operate will be reused in future.
2. When you get a converted view passed by `getView()` method, the specific converted view might have been used before, so make sure to update all the attributes which might be dirty for current converted view.

Should be kind of below code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            view = createSpecificView();
        }

        updateSpecificView(view);//update all attributes here.
        return view;
    }
```

Hopefully can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY reason you need to return the convertView at the end of getView() is for the situation where it was null and/or you create a new instance.  When an object is passed as a parameter, you can modify the underlying object's state but cannot change or create a new object.  You can't change which object convertView points to.

So, you also return the convertView at the end of the method.  This covers the situation where you create a new object.